# send Images in chats using PHP + jQuery + MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a chat application which works absolutely fine for sending and receiving texts only but I want to send images/videos/ files through it.

This is the main home page which display the chats.

```
<script>
  $ = jQuery;
  var currentID = null;
  var chatTimer = null;
  var oldhtml="";

  function fetch_data() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "select.php",
      method: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#live_data').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  function fetch_chat() {   
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch_chat.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        id: currentID
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#chatbox").show();
        $('#messages').html(data);
        $("div.area").show();
        if(oldhtml!==data) {
          $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
        oldhtml=data;
      }    
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {    
    fetch_data();
    setInterval(function() {
      fetch_chat();
    }, 500);
    $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
      currentID = $(this).data("id1");
      fetch_chat();
    });
    $("#sub").click(function() {
      var text = $("#text").val();
      $.post('insert_chat.php', {
        id: currentID,
        msg: text
      }, function(data) {
        $("#messages").append(data);
        $("#text").val('');       
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

and below is the fetch_chat.php which fetches the chat from databases.

```
<?php
  require("config.php");
  $user_to = $_POST['id'];
  $res1=$db->query("select * from chats where user_from='$_SESSION[id]' AND 
user_to='$user_to' OR user_to='$_SESSION[id]' AND user_from='$user_to' order 
by id");
  if($res1->num_rows){
    while($row=$res1->fetch_object()){
      if($row->user_from === $_SESSION["id"] ) {
        echo "<div class='chat self'>
          <div class='user-photo'><img src='img/user1.jpg'></div>
          <p class='chat-message'> $row->msg</p>
        </div>";
      }  else {
        echo "<div class='chat friend'>
          <div class='user-photo'><img src='img/user2.jpg'></div>
          <p class='chat-message'>$row->msg</p>
        </div>";
      }
    }
  } else
    echo "No msgs <br />";
?>
```

Now I want to save the info of the uploaded file in the database and the files into a folder/directory. The sender and receiver should be able to send and view the files respectively.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing astutely positioned parentheses from the query above?

Comment: what do u mean by that?

Comment: I suspect you meant `where a='x' or (b='y' and c='z')`